# How to see OUT parameters in mysql workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I can `CALL` a stored procedure from MySQL Workbench, but I am not seeing what any of the returned out-params are.

Say I have a procedure `PROCEDURE test(IN id int, OUT name tinytext)` - how can I call this from a query window to check it returns the right thing?

Comment: Let me say some words about the [dbForge Studio for MySQL](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/) (free express edition). You can execute procedure from the Database Explorer tree, pass IN paremeters and view OUT paremeters in window.

Answer (score 4):

You need to `SELECT` the `OUT` parameter.

```
CALL test(1, @v); SELECT @v;
```

Please note: You have to execute both queries at once (hit control+enter with the cursor at the end of the line). Also, the current version of the workbench seems to have a bug, it didn't work with arbitrary parameter names. I can't get out the pattern when it does work and when it doesn't at the moment.